# Retaining selected values on form submit

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I'm unable to retain selected values (a multi-select) on form submit. Do you see an issue?

```
  <select name='colors[]' id="colors" class="selectpicker" multiple>
      <option value='<?php echo $row['table_name']; ?>'>
           <?php if(isset($_POST['colors'])) {echo implode(',', $_POST['colors'])} else {echo $row['table_name']} ?>
      </option>
  </select>
```

Comment: What is your expecting result? Can you show?

Comment: Please don't repost.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I'm yet figuring out the site. Sure will delete as appropriate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If in `$_POST['colors']` you have array of colors, then:

```
 <select name='colors[]' id="colors" class="selectpicker" multiple>
       <?php 
        foreach ($_POST['colors'] as $color {
           echo "<option>{$color}</option>";
        }
       ?>
    </option>
 </select>
```

Comment: My issue is slightly different. If you go through the 3rd line, and if I replace that with `echo $row['table_name']` the multi-select would just work fine. However on form submit the selected values will not retain. Do you have a workaround for that?